# How to set a form class?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using symfony 2.4 and I'm looking for a way to programatically add a class name to a form, in my twig template I have:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.firstname) }}
{{ form_row(form.lastname) }}
{{ form_row(form.company) }}
{{ form_row(form.email) }}
{{ form_row(form.phone1) }}
{{ form_row(form.phone2) }}
{{ form_row(form.fax) }}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="{{ 'Save' | trans }}" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

I was successful at creating a template within my bundle to add a class to the input fields, now I need to do the same for the **form** tag, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#reference-form-twig-variables

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'foo'} }) }}
```

The above snippet worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ form_start(form, {'class': 'your_class'}) }}
```

Comment: I didn't work, I even cleared the cache and the form tag still renders without a class attribute.